# php add different string on an nth char of a string

Tags: php, string

I found this code that replaces the second char or index of a string.

```
$string="blah";
$string=substr_replace($string,"",1,1);
```

but instead, i want to have a string added on the second index of a string.

```
$input = 'asdf';
$string_to_be_added = 'eee';
$output = 'aseeedf';
```

what should be changed in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing incorrect arguments. The correct syntax and order is:

```
substr_replace ($string, $replacement, $start, $length);
```

You need the string to be added to the second position, so supply `2` as the `start` parameter:

```
$newstring = substr_replace($input, $string_to_be_added, 2, 0);
```

Output:

```
string(7) "aseeedf"
```